# How to Draw Deflection Curve Underneath a Beam?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Wondering how I could draw the deflection curve underneath a simply supported beam in dashed lines with the `y = ?` label as shown:
[image]

I am using the `structuralanalysis` package.  Below is the code I've created so far:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0.99in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{structuralanalysis}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, step =.45]
(0,-3.95) grid(9.115,3.325);
\scaling{.45};
\point{a}{0}{0};
\support{2}{a};
\point{b}{20}{0};
\support{2}{b};
\beam{2}{a}{b}[0][20];
\notation{5}{a}{b}[$\text{w}_{\text{f}} = 19.2 \ \text{kN/m}$][.5][above = 
15.5 mm];
\lineload{2}{a}{b}[1.20][1.20][0.0625];
\dimensioning{1}{a}{b}{ -1.125}[\textbf{$\ell = $}];
\notation{1}{a}{Gridline 4}[left = 2.5 mm];
\notation{1}{b}{Gridline 6}[right = 2.5 mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete, compilable document beginning with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` In it is important preamble. It should contain only necessary stuff for your image.

Comment: For hinged edges, deformed shape should be parabolic (possibly cannonical).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the package has been renamed structuralanalysis to stanli !

TexLive 2019

Curve draw:

```
\internalforces{a}{b}{0}{0}[-1.5][black];
```

Exam file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{stanli}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\point{a}{0}{0};
\point{ab}{0}{-.2};
\point{b}{4}{0};
\point{c}{2}{.5};
\point{d}{2}{-2};
\beam{2}{a}{b}[0][3];
\beam{3}{c}{d}[0][4];
\internalforces{a}{b}{0}{0}[-1.5][black];
\notation {1}{a}{$x=0$}[left];
\notation {1}{ab}{$y=0$}[below left];
\notation {1}{b}{$x=L$}[right];
\notation {1}{d}{$\theta=0$}[right];
\draw [<->,very thick] (2,-.3)--(2,-1.2)node[left,midway]{$y=?$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @M.Ahmadi, regarding the "\internalforces" command, the optional parameter regarding the height of the parabola, In case the starting and the ending points are set to zero, then the height is the distance from the center of the datum to the parabola. However, if one end of the parabola is negative and the other is positive. in this case what does the height represent, I have an issue comprehending this

Comment: Hello, I will answer your question, I hope it will be useful. in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568148)

Answer (score 0):

Showed image is simple to draw with pure TikZ:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     block/.style = {align=left, yshift=-\baselineskip},
shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1},
                > = Straight Barb
                        ]
\draw   (-3,0) coordinate (a) -- (3,0) coordinate (b)
        (a) to [bend right=45] coordinate (c)   (b);
\node[block, left]  at (a)  {$x=0$\\    $y=0$\\ $\Phi=?$};
\node[block, right] at (b)  {$x=L$\\    $y=0$\\ $\Phi=?$};
\node[below right]  at (c)  {$\Phi=0$};
\draw[densely dash dot, shorten <>=-3mm]    (c) -- (0,0);
\draw[<->, semithick, shorten <>=1mm]       (c) to ["$y=?$"]    (0,0); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For some other solution (using your code) you should provide MWE (minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which we can test as it is.

Comment: Hi Zarko, I've just entered my code.  Any chance you may be able to show it with that? Thank you again.

Comment: @ballislyfe24, sorry, I'm not familiar with the package `structuralanalysis`. For solution with it you should wait on some other answer.

Comment: I used your code and adjusted it to mine and I was able to draw the dashed deflection line of the beam.  Your code solved my problem, so thank you again! I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[margin=0.99in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{structuralanalysis}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, step =.45]
(0,-3.95) grid(9.115,3.325);
\scaling{.45};
\point{a}{0}{0};
\support{2}{a};
\point{b}{20}{0};
\support{2}{b};
\point{c}{5}{0}
\beam{2}{a}{b}[0][20];
\notation{5}{a}{b}[$\text{w}_{\text{f}} = ? \ \text{kN/m}$][.5][above = 15.5 mm];
\lineload{2}{a}{b}[1.20][1.20][0.0625];
\dimensioning{1}{a}{b}{-1.5}[\textbf{$\ell = $}];
\notation{1}{a}{}[left = 2.5 mm];
\notation{1}{b}{}[right = 2.5 mm];
\draw [densely dashed,color=blue] (0,0) coordinate (a) -- (8.975,0) coordinate (b)
    (a) to [bend right=15] coordinate (c)   (b);
\draw[<->, semithick] (c) to ["${\Delta} = $"]    (4.5,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```